# Access Cisco AnyConnect VPN from Linux Mint 18

Tags: ubuntu, networking, linux-mint, networkmanager, vpn

From the Cisco AnyConnect client (Mac and Android), I connect to a given VPN using *only*:

- Server Address
- Username
- Password

How do I accomplish the same in Linux Mint 18.1 (based on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial)?

I have the `network-manager-vpnc-gnome` package, which is what I assume I need; however it requires a "Group Name."

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
# use your own vpn gateway
my_vpn_gateway=your.vpn.gateway.com

# connect
sudo openvpn --mktun --dev tun1
sudo ifconfig tun1 up
# this command will prompt for credentials
sudo openconnect $my_vpn_gateway --interface=tun1

# disconnect
sudo ifconfig tun1 down
sudo openvpn --rmtun --dev tun1
```

Source: http://tuxdiary.com/2014/09/04/cisco-anyconnect-vpn-with-openvpn-openconnect/

Comment: While this works, I'll hold off a bit on marking it as _the_ answer in case a GUI solution turns up.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `Server IP address:Port` (e.g.: 111.111.111.111:443) in `Gateway`. [**Note** : Make sure to replace with actual IP of the router and the port over which the VPN is running)
2. Use `User Name` and `Password` and keep `Group name` blank.
3. In `IPv4` tab chose `Automatic` option and save it.

Comment: Thanks, Abhik, but as I mentioned in the OP, `Group name` is required--the Save button is disabled if it is empty.

Comment: Ok. Try once with `username` as `group name`, incase it works.